Problem with transparent color textures overlaying other objects in OBJ format
I need to output the sakura model (obj format). I have a frame that I apply textures to. The problem is that when applying flower textures, the transparent parts seem to overlap other objects, although in theory they should be transparent and other objects should be visible through them.

Image where the transparent part of the flower overlaps the branch


I have triangles that I overlay with an image of a flower. I made the frame itself transparent, the picture I am overlaying also has a transparent part and an opaque flower. But when overlaying the transparency does not work correctly. Here is the code with an example with two flowers.
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Media.Media3D;

namespace WpfApp4;

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
            InitializeComponent();
            LoadModel();
        }

        private void LoadModel()
        {
            var obj = new Object3D
            {
                vertices = new[]
                {
                    new Point3D(4, 15, -10),
                    new Point3D(3, 16, -9),
                    new Point3D(4, 16, -10),
                    new Point3D(4, 16, -10),
                    new Point3D(4, 16, -8),
                    new Point3D(5, 17, -10)
                },
                normals = new[]
                {
                    new Vector3D(-1, 0, -1),
                    new Vector3D(0, 1, 0)
                },
                texCoords = new[]
                {
                    new Point(1, 0),
                    new Point(0, 1),
                    new Point(0, 0),
                    new Point(1, 0),
                    new Point(0, 1),
                    new Point(0, 0)
                },
                surfaces = new[]
                {
                    new Surface { vertices = new[] { 0, 1, 2 } },
                    new Surface { vertices = new[] { 3, 4, 5 } }
                },
                material = new MaterialInfo
                {
                    diffuseColor = Colors.White,
                    emissiveColor = Colors.Black,
                    specularColor = Colors.Gray,
                    reflectionIndex = 0.5,
                    material_file_name = "flower.png"
                }
            };

            var model = AddObjectToScene(obj);
            Viewport3D.Children.Add(model);
        }

        private ModelVisual3D AddObjectToScene(Object3D obj)
        {
            var model = new ModelVisual3D();
            var model3D = new GeometryModel3D();
            var mesh = new MeshGeometry3D();
            
            var normals = new Vector3DCollection
            {
                new Vector3D(-1, 0, -1), 
                new Vector3D(0, 1, 0)    
            };
            mesh.Normals = normals;
            var positions = new Point3DCollection
            {
                new Point3D(4, 15, -10),
                new Point3D(3, 16, -9),
                new Point3D(4, 16, -10),
                new Point3D(4, 15, -11),
                new Point3D(3, 16, -10),
                new Point3D(4, 16, -11)
            };
            mesh.Positions = positions;
            
            var triangleIndices = new Int32Collection { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
            mesh.TriangleIndices = triangleIndices;

            mesh.TextureCoordinates = new PointCollection
            {
                new Point(1, 0.5),
                new Point(0.5, 1),
                new Point(0, 0),
                new Point(1, 0.5),
                new Point(0.5, 1),
                new Point(0, 0)
            };

            model3D.Geometry = mesh;
            
            var myMaterialGroup = new MaterialGroup();
            Material mt1 = new DiffuseMaterial(new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0,255,255,255)));
            Material mt2 = new EmissiveMaterial(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black));
            Material mt3 = new SpecularMaterial(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray), 0.5);

            Material texture = null;
                var imageBrush = new ImageBrush
                {
                    ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(obj.material.material_file_name, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)),
                    Opacity = 1
                };
                texture = new DiffuseMaterial(imageBrush);

            myMaterialGroup.Children.Add(mt1);
            myMaterialGroup.Children.Add(mt3);
            myMaterialGroup.Children.Add(mt2);

            if (texture != null)
                myMaterialGroup.Children.Add(texture);

            model3D.Material = myMaterialGroup;

            model.Content = model3D;
            return model;
        }
    }

    public class Object3D
    {
        public Point3D[] vertices { get; set; }
        public Vector3D[] normals { get; set; }
        public Point[] texCoords { get; set; }
        public Surface[] surfaces { get; set; }
        public MaterialInfo material { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class Surface
    {
        public int[] vertices { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class MaterialInfo
    {
        public Color diffuseColor { get; set; }
        public Color emissiveColor { get; set; }
        public Color specularColor { get; set; }
        public double reflectionIndex { get; set; }
        public string material_file_name { get; set; }
    }


and camera
<Window x:Class="WpfApp4.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:helix="http://helix-toolkit.org/wpf"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="3D Viewer" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid Background="SkyBlue">
        <helix:HelixViewport3D x:Name="Viewport3D" ZoomExtentsWhenLoaded="true" Grid.RowSpan="2">
            <helix:HelixViewport3D.Camera>
                <PerspectiveCamera Position="0,0,5" LookDirection="0,0.2,1" UpDirection="2,2,2" FieldOfView="45" />
            </helix:HelixViewport3D.Camera>
            
            <helix:SunLight />
        </helix:HelixViewport3D>
    </Grid>
</Window>


Important note: the 3D model looks normal in viewers. Also, as part of the assignment, I cannot use OpenGl and other advanced libraries.

what are you using to draw these presumed textured polygons? consider presenting a [mre]

@Christoph Rackwitz I am using WPF with Viewport3D to render the 3D scene. Code is also added now.
